# Update service references in multiple projects?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2008

I have a visual studio 2008 solution with approximately 15 projects. Several of these projects have a WCF service reference to a WCF service project.  Whenever I update the service project, I have to go to each of the other projects and right click the service reference and update it.  Is there an easier way to do this, like a "Update All Service References In Solution" button, somewhere, somehow?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516098/update-all-wcf-service-references-in-one-click-two-clicks-would-be-ok-too And none of them include an example of the svcutil.exe script...too bad..now i have to learn more ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There's no such functionality, really - at least none that I'd be aware of.

You could do one of two things:

- have [`svcutil.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) update your service references - it's a command line tool, which you can batch up, or have executed during a build process

or:

- if you're controlling both ends of the communication channel, and both are .NET, you could put your service and data contracts into a separate assembly (or several), and then share those assemblies between server side and client side code. You'd have to change the way you build up your client side proxies a bit (instantiate a `ChannelFactory<T>` and create the channel from that factory for each service contract), but that would be a one-time effort.

  Once done, any updates to the service and/or data contracts would be reflected in both the server side code, as well as your client proxy code.

  The only drawback here is: it only works for .NET-to-.NET communication - if you have non-.NET clients, those are left out in the cold, obviously.....

Comment: I'll have to play around with those options, and will post my results here later.